# No resource identifier found for attribute 'textsize' in package 'android'

Tags: android, android-layout, android-studio

> Error:(14) No resource identifier found for attribute 'text size' in
>   package 'android' Error:Execution failed for task
>   ':app:processDebugResources'. 
>   com.android.ide.common.process.ProcessException:
>   org.gradle.process.internal.ExecException: Process 'command
>   '/home/shubham/Android/Sdk/build-tools/23.0.1/aapt'' finished with
>   non-zero exit value 1

When i was run the program its gives above error. how i resolve it?

Comment: Make sure it's `android:textSize`, no space

Comment: thank you problem solved

Comment: Thanks, I have added it as an answer. If this solved your problem please don't forget to mark it as accepted: http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/5235

Answer (score 2):

Make sure you use the "textSize" attribute - no spaces!

```
<TextView
    android:textSize="16sp"
    ... />
```

http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/TextView.html#attr_android:textSize